# Differences between Silverlight's HtmlPage.Window.Navigate and HyperlinkButton?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0, hyperlink

I'm trying to get my Silverlight 4.0 application to launch the associated program file a file extension when the user clicks something to take them to its web URL, but I'm having difference experiences whether I use HtmlPage.Window.Navigate or HyperlinkButton.

My web URL is a RESTful URL to my resource, e.g. "http://.../objects/object-1/package".  The URL is actually an ASP.NET MVC 2 controller that returns zip content with a custom extension.  That is, the HTTP response headers look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 17:22:19 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=object-1.pkg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/zip
Connection: Close
```

When I use a hyperlinkbutton, Internet Explorer prompts me to Open, Save or Cancel.  When I choose Open, it opens the application I have associated with *.pkg:

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="http://localhost:8023/objects/object-1/package">Launch!</HyperlinkButton>
```

However, if I instead use a command that ultimate uses HtmlPage.Window.Navigate, IE just opens a window and then quickly closes:

```
string url = string.Format("{0}/objects/object-{1}/package", _webBaseUrl, objectId.Value);
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank");
```

I've verified using Fiddler2 that in both cases, the HTTP requests and HTTP responses look identical.  This appears to be either an Internet Explorer or Silverlight nuance that I'm not sure I can overcome, but I hope the Stackoverflow community can confirm or deny this problem.

Comment: We are experiencing the same behavior with downloading of excel files. It seems that click on HyperlinkButton is treated as safer than HtmlPage.Window.Navigate and IE handles such requests differently.

Comment: I think this other question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927571/silverlight-hyperlink-button-and-unc-path

Answer (score 1):

There's a brief article [here](http://stulic.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/javascript-locationhref-vs-silverlight.html) that shed some light on this issue - I found that `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate` didn't work for me at all outside of IE.

But going back to the original question, using dotPeek I could see the following differences:

Tracking the HyperlinkButton OnClick, it delegates the call to agcore: (XcpImports.cs)

```
[DllImport("agcore", EntryPoint = "NavigateToSafeURI", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static uint NavigateToSafeURINative(IntPtr context, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string location, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string target, bool checkUserInitiatedAction);
```

and HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri) makes this call:

```
[DllImport("agcore")]
public static int DOM_Invoke(IntPtr pBrowserService, IntPtr pObject, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszMethodName, int nArgCount, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] NativeMethods.ScriptParam[] ppParams, ref NativeMethods.ScriptParam pResult, ref NativeMethods.ExceptionInfo pExcepInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a popup blocker issue.

Have you tried this in any other browsers or with the Navigate overload that just takes a Uri?

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri);
```

Comment: I have no popup blockers on turned on.  And in fact, in the HamlPage.Window.Navigate case the popup actually does occur and remains open while the download is ongoing (since it's my code producing the downloaded stream, I can easily pause it with a breakpoint).  IE just closes that popup window when the download completes and never does anything with the downloaded file (i.e. launch the associated program).

Comment: And, no I've not tried the single parameter version.  The MSDN docs say that will navigate in the current window which I fear would dispose of my running Silverlight app.

Comment: It's really down to the operating system to handle the downloaded file, not IE. I **suspect** that you don't have a handler configured for the pkg file type you're trying to download. I'm sure you've experienced file downloads where the download link doesn't reload the current page as it's handled outside of IE. As a test why don't you try and change this... _Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=object-1.pkg_ to return a _.zip_ filename. If it works it's your OS file associations that are the problem