# Silverlight Hyperlink Button and UNC Path

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I have a hyperlink button on a silverlight page.  The NavigateUri property is set to a UNC folder path (\\myserver\folder).  In Silverlight 4 I could click on the link and it would open the folder (after prompting the user to Allow access).  In Silverlight 5 clicking on the link produces a javascript error (shown below).  Is this a new restriction with Silverlight 5?  Is there a work around?

Thanks

```
Webpage error details


Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.NavigateToSafeURI(String location, String target, Boolean checkUserInitiatedAction)
at MS.Internal.NavigationHelper.Navigate(Boolean checkUserInitiatedAction)
at System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a new restriction introduced in Silverlight 5. They revamped the security model to make it more secure but to also explicitly allow for this behaviour.

You can now run trusted application in the browser rather than as out-of-browser applications. You need to configure the application as though it were going to be a trusted OOB application as the "Require elevated trust" and "Show install menu" settings are part of the OOB configuration.

To enable in browser trusted applications you need to edit the registry on the client machine:

> Create/Set **AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser** to 1

This can be found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\` for 32 bit machines or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432NodeaMicrosoft\Silverlight\` for 64 bit.

In addition the .xap files must be signed with a valid certificate and the certificate must be installed.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)